# How can I find out where mysterious "bing bong" sounds are coming from?

Tags: notifications, monterey

I've only been a Mac user for less than a year, and a thing that's driven me crazy is that I get "bing bong" alerts (or something) every once in a while, but I cannot figure out where they're coming from. The Notification Center always says there are no recent alerts, even if I open it immediately after a "bing bong".

I'm sure those noises are intended to be helpful, but if I have no idea what they mean I think that the goal is not being achieved. Is there some centralized "Preferences" thing where I can find out what they are?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115286/alert-sound-on-the-hour-every-hour-osx-and-ios) at AskDifferent is pertinent to your situation.

Comment: @IconDaemon thank you for the suggestion. However, the Monterey Date/Time preference UI does not look like that now, and I don't see any "Announce Time" option.

Comment: Is it the same sound as your System Alerts (in System Prefs > Sound), or a different sound?

Comment: It's a pleasant synthesized bell-like sound, two quick notes, the first a little higher-pitched than the second. None of the "System Sounds" match, so it must (?) be some random application.

Comment: I know that when I accidentally start the native mail client, if it's hooked up to my gmail account it never shuts up, but that's not the issue here because the mail client isn't running as far as I can tell.